# Use Personalized Web Part Views WSS 3.0?

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I want to use "Explorer View" for just myself.  I can create default views for web parts, however I can't seem to see the view selector when I select "Personalize this Page" feature from WSS 3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebPartStorage is set to Shared and not User for the List View Webparts view-selector. Therefore the property is not available in personalized mode.

Comment: What he (JMD) said. You've (Danny) asked for something that's impossible. Sorry.